# How to use multiple group by conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a customer_master table. In that table I have two columns called customer_id and date_of_birth.

what I want is get count of customers group by their age ranger.  Something like this.

[image]

So far this is the only query I could try.

**select COUNT(customer_id) AS count FROM customer_master
WHERE (DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),date_of_birth) / 365.25)<40**

Please help me out with this. Thank you.

With everyone's help I found a perfect answer than you all.

```
SELECT CASE

 WHEN (DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(date_of_birth, '%Y-%m-%d')) / 365) <= 20 THEN 'Below 20'
            WHEN(DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(date_of_birth, '%Y-%m-%d')) / 365) <= 30 THEN 'Below 30'
            WHEN (DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(date_of_birth, '%Y-%m-%d')) / 365) <= 40 THEN 'Below 40'
            WHEN (DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(date_of_birth, '%Y-%m-%d')) / 365) <= 50 THEN 'Below 50'
    ELSE 'Over 50'
   END as age_group, 
   COUNT(customer_id) 

 FROM customer_master 
 GROUP BY age_group;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) operator.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (DATEDIFF( CURDATE(),date_of_birth) / 365.25) < 40 THEN 'Below 40'
         ELSE 'Over 40'
       END as age_group, 
       COUNT(customer_id) 
FROM customer_master 
GROUP BY age_group;
```

Sorry for poor formatting, it is my first answer

Comment: thank you for your answer it only need on bracket. If you correct this I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use cascading values with CASE within a subquery:

```
select age_group, count(customer_id) as 'count' from
    (select customer_id,
       year(curdate())-year(date_of_birth) as 'age',
       case when (year(curdate())-year(date_of_birth)) < 20, "Below 20"
       when (year(curdate())-year(date_of_birth)) < 30, "Between 20 and 29"
       when (year(curdate())-year(date_of_birth)) < 40, "Between 30 and 39"
       else "40 or Greater" end as 'age_group'
    FROM customer_master) x
group by age_group
```

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' "Below 20",
       when (year(curdate())-year(date_of_birth)) < 30, "Between 2' at line 4

Comment: I had a few commas that shouldn't have been there. Edited to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  (year(curdate())-year(date_of_birth)) div 20 as age_group,
  COUNT(customer_id)
FROM 
  customer_master
GROUP BY age_group
```

Something like this will give you number of customers in every 20. If you want different size of group just change the number you divide by.

That is assuming you want each group to be same size e.g

```
1 - 20
21 - 40
41 - 60
...
```

If you want different sizes go with CASE solution as other have suggested.